# Trying to use Adaptive Simple Payments but get blank screen

Tags: php, json, curl, paypal

I'm trying to figure out how to use Adaptive Simple Payments with Paypal API and trying to test their default code:

```
$payRequest = new PayRequest();

$receiver = array();
$receiver[0] = new Receiver();
$receiver[0]->amount = "1.00";
$receiver[0]->email = "platfo_1255170694_biz@gmail.com";
$receiverList = new ReceiverList($receiver);
$payRequest->receiverList = $receiverList;

$requestEnvelope = new RequestEnvelope("en_US");
$payRequest->requestEnvelope = $requestEnvelope; 
$payRequest->actionType = "PAY";
$payRequest->cancelUrl = "https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/ap_simple_payment/php?cancel=true";
$payRequest->returnUrl = "https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/ap_simple_payment/php?success=true";
$payRequest->currencyCode = "USD";
$payRequest->ipnNotificationUrl = "http://replaceIpnUrl.com";

$sdkConfig = array(
    "mode" => "sandbox",
    "acct1.UserName" => "reznik.demarket-facilitator_api1.gmail.com",
    "acct1.Password" => "BV5GBSV7QBPXJUNR",
    "acct1.Signature" => "AcK.GqlanslGMma1L2TIOPx.t0xQApMepP-Rt7jundLbNOzkwOhrqbJ4",
    "acct1.AppId" => "APP-80W284485P519543T"
);

$adaptivePaymentsService = new AdaptivePaymentsService($sdkConfig);
$payResponse = $adaptivePaymentsService->Pay($payRequest);
```

it should give me json answer like that:

```
{"responseEnvelope":{"timestamp":"2015-02-26T17:14:06.242-08:00","ack":"Success","correlationId":"aae1f46492b42","build":"15089777"},"payKey":"AP-0SN13003KN641223K","paymentExecStatus":"CREATED"}
```

Why can i get a blank screen without any errors or success messages?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're getting a PHP error but you don't have errors being displayed on the server.  Try adding this to the top of your script...

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

That should allow you to see the error that is happening so you can fix it.